# Hardcode a subtitle file in ts file

Tags: video-streaming

I am trying to transmit a ts file from server which should be embedded with a given SRT file. I want the subtitle to be hardcoded to the video. Any suggestions on how can I do this?

Comment: "Hard coded" does not have meaning in this context. What do you mean by "hard coded" do you mean "burned in" or do you mean "in band"

Comment: yes @szatmary i mean "burned in"

Comment: Ffmpeg can do this easily. Just google it.